# How do you add a character string for every second row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to concatenate one string to every second row for only one column:

From this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| A    |   11 |
| B    |   22 |
| A    |   22 |
| A    |   33 |
| A    |   44 |

+------+------+
```

To this (adding _a to the first col):

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| A    |   11 |
| B_a  |   22 |
| A    |   22 |
| A_a  |   33 |
| A    |   44 |
+------+------+
```

Thank you for your help! Preferably I would like to use paste0() or anything in the tidyverse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df %>%
 mutate(col1 = if_else(row_number() %% 2 == 0, paste0(col1, "_A"), col1))

  col1 col2
1    A   11
2  B_A   22
3    A   22
4  A_A   33
5    A   44
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked!

Answer (score 2):

Using vector recycling in base R:

```
df$col1 <- paste0(df$col1, c("", "_a"))
df
  col1 col2
1    A   11
2  B_a   22
3    A   22
4  A_a   33
5    A   44
```

Reproducible example (please provide it yourself next time):

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A"),
  col2 = c(11, 22, 22, 33, 44),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: how does it affect every SECOND row?

Comment: @JayAr it pastes `""`, that is nothing, to the first row, then `"_a"` to the second row and repeats until `df$col1` is finished. Another example: `paste(1:9, letters[1:3])`

Answer (score 1):

We can use vector recycling to subset alternate values of `col1` and `paste` `"a_"` to it.

```
df$col1[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- paste0(df$col1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], "_a")
df
#  col1 col2
#1    A   11
#2  B_a   22
#3    A   22
#4  A_a   33
#5    A   44
```

Make sure `col1` is of class character and not factor.